# How to show my application as referral in Wordpress Stats

Tags: url-rewriting

I have a desktop application that links to my wordpress website.
Whenever a user clicks on the link in the application it opens my website in browser.
However how can I track how many people are coming to wordpress site via desktop application.
Presently the desktop application is not listed in referral section in wordpress stats.
Only some search engines and other links are shown.
Thanks
Nitin

Comment: Are you using a 3rd party analytics service? For example, with Google Analytics you can pass a `utm_campaign` URL parameter from your application so you can easily track all clicks from within your dashboard.

Comment: Is there a way where I can pass some value in url which wordpress can read and show in the referral section.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to directly set a referrer.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14235377/http-referer-and-bookmark

You can still track this data by passing a parameter in the url and then listening for that parameter in WordPress.  For example, you could set the parameter `from_desktop` in the url, so your url would look like `www.example.com/page-slug/?from_desktop=1`.  Once you've got this going to the correct link, you need to capture that parameter in WordPress.  You'll need to hook at an appropriate time, `init` perhaps, and then test the URL to see if your parameter is in there with either `$_GET['from_desktop']` or `$_REQUEST['from_desktop']`.  Once you have determined the parameter is there, it's up to you to track it.

Basic code:

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpse177648_url_check' );
function wpse177648_url_check() {
    if( 1 == $_GET['from_desktop'] ) {
        // Came from the desktop app. Do logic here.
    }
}
```